# Element behaving like block despite being inline-block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want my `priority-menu` (the one with 2 dots) to have the 3 dots displayed horizontally. Since each individual dot is `inline-block` I don't understand why they are stacked on top of one another. The menu is rendered by clicking on the blue circle on the right of the "save task" button, which changes its display to `inline` instead of `none`. I tried changing that to `inline-block` and nothing seems to have changed.

```
/* The popup menu - hidden by default */
#priority-menu {      
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;    
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;    
    max-width: 300px;    
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;          
}

#priority-dot-open-menu { 
    position: relative;   
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#priority-dot-open-menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


#priority-dot-blue {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

#priority-dot-yellow {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

#priority-dot-red {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 0;
}


#priority-menu::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;  /* At the top of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  }
```

```
<div class="modal-footer d-flex flex-row justify-content-start pl-0 mt-4 border-0">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add-task-modal-save">Save task</button>
  <span id="priority-dot-open-menu">
  <span id="priority-menu">
  <span class="tooltip-top"></span>
  <span id="priority-dot-blue"></span>
  <span id="priority-dot-yellow"></span>
  <span id="priority-dot-red"></span>
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can  you make a working snippet of your menu

Comment: Can you provide the JS.
I have added bootstrap-4 dependency too. It is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `priority-menu` is contained within an element which you’ve set to 25px width. Try removing this and changing to 300px, like your `priority-menu`.

```
#priority-dot-open-menu { 
    position: relative;   
    height: 25px
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

You can also try adding a declared `width` to your menu instead of just a `max-width`.

```
#priority-menu {
    width:300px;
}
```